# Hiding and showing android layouts - How do you mark active layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, visibility

I'm just writing my first android app and in one layout xml file I have four buttons that will display a different layout when pressed.  Instead of creating four seperate screens, I've just put the four layouts in the same layout as the buttons with android:visibility="GONE", and then when a button is pressed, I set it's corresponding layout to being visible.

My question is, is there a best practice or suggested method for keeping track of the active layout so that when a button is pressed you can set the active layout back to visibility="GONE" before making the new one visible.  I thought I could just set a string value with the ID of the active layout, but then findViewById wont take the string to get a hold of the layout.  Any help or suggestions would be great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use a string to save the ID of the layout? Can you not just use an int since the ID's are such? Or set the visibility of the layouts from the onClickListener you attached to each button?

Comment: I'm just saying using a string was my first thought, not set on using it at all.  How does the id name, i.e - R.id.textview1, translate into an int?  If storing it as an int, is there a best practice for storing global variables like that in android?

Comment: You should check the documentation better: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29 (it accepts an int) and http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html (search for "R class" in that page). Still, why don't you set the visibility from the listeners instead of storing the id?

Comment: I am setting the visibility in the onclicklistener for the current button being pressed, but I need a way to know which was the previously pressed button so that I can set its' visibility back to "GONE".

Comment: Looks like I can use a resource stored as an xml file in res/values as shown here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Integer

Comment: If you have 4 buttons and four layouts, I would do something like this (repeat for each):
button1-2-3-4=(Button)findViewByID(R.id.button1-2-3-4);
layout1-2-3-4=(WhateverLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1-2-3-4);
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
  onclick(View v){
    layout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    layout2-3-4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
});
But do whatever you feel it's best for you, good luck!